# Cannot compile in preview

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

Error: Cannot compile Build method due to parameters mismatch. Type needs parameterless ctor or ctor with single IServiceProvider argument, or x:Arguments directive with matching arguments

MainView.axaml

```cs
<UserControl
    x:Class="AvaloniaApplication1.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AvaloniaApplication1.ViewModels"
    x:DataType="vm:Class1"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainView.axaml.cs

```cs
using Avalonia.Controls;
using AvaloniaApplication1.ViewModels;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace AvaloniaApplication1.Views;

public partial class MainView : UserControl
{
    public MainView(Class1 class1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = class1;
    }
}
```

Class1.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AvaloniaApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class Class1 : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Class1()
        {
            Name = "Tom";
        }
    }
}
```

I can build application without error but in preview i i have this error.

Comment: When reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is says: "**Help others reproduce the problem**".  But it is not clear what the error message is saying, so it will always be unclear if the problem is reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the previewer to function, you have to have a public parameterless constructor.  If you're accustomed to other UI (WPF, Winforms, etc), their previewers will automatically pass default(T) to a parameterized constructor if they can't find a parameterless constructor but Avalonia's previewer unfortunately doesn't at this time.

You do not have to use it in your code, and you can optionally wrap it in `#if DEBUG` if you want.  The bit about IServiceProvider is not correct, I've tried that, but it fails. That's how it would typically be done with dependency injection but even with that constructor, the previewer fails.  Just add this back in addition to your parameterized constructor:

```cs
public MainView()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
```